# Antlr Lexer Parse error

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr3

Antlr version: antlr-dotnet-tool-3.5.0.2

TestGrammar.g

```
lexer grammar TestGrammar;

options
{
    language=CSharp3;   
    backtrack=true; 
}

DOT
    :   '.'
    ;

NUMBER
    :   ( '0'..'9' )+ ('.' ( '0'..'9' )+)?
    ;

WS  
    : (' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'|'\n') {$channel=Hidden;}
    ;
```

C# code:

```
        var lexer = new TestGrammar(new ANTLRStringStream("2..3"));
        while (true)
        {
            var token = lexer.NextToken();
            Console.WriteLine(token);

            if (token.Type == -1)
                break;
        }
```

Result:

```
[@-1,3:3='3',<5>,1:3]
[@-1,4:4='<EOF>',<-1>,1:4]
```

So, I test this grammar  with input

```
2..3
```

I expect that the result will be the following:

```
NUMBER["2"] DOT["."] DOT["."] NUMBER["3"]
```

So, what am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: What do you get as result?

Comment: I input '2 ..3 - lexer work right. NUMBER WS DOT DOT NUMBER

Answer (score 0):

Testing with the Java target:

```
TestGrammar lexer = new TestGrammar(new ANTLRInputStream("2..3"));

for (Token t : lexer.getAllTokens()) {
  System.out.printf("%s -> %s\n", t.getText(), TestGrammar.VOCABULARY.getSymbolicName(t.getType()));
}
```

produces the following output:

```
2 -> NUMBER
. -> DOT
. -> DOT
3 -> NUMBER
```

So, the grammar is correct. I doubt that the C# runtime would produce anything other than what I posted (with the C# equivalent test class). If it still doesn't work, please edit your question and add some code that demonstrates how to reproduce the error(s) you get.